# SSH through proxy with nc and no_proxy variable

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy

I'm behind a HTTP proxy and I'm trying to connect to a remote machine from my Ubuntu note via ssh. If I configure my .ssh/config as

```
Host test
HostName  55.66.77.88
ProxyCommand nc -X connect -x proxy.corp.com:8080 %h %p
User test_user
```

I can connect to the remote machine. There are other users on my network (using OSX) can connect to the same machine adding the IP of the machine to the `no_proxy` variable, without the nc on ssh/config. If I add the machine on my `no_proxy` variable on `zshenv`:

```
no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,55.66.77.88"
NO_PROXY=$no_proxy
```

and check my terminal, the variable is set (after export):

```
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,55.66.77.88
```

but now I can't connect to the machine. What can be going wrong? I believe that the `no_proxy` variable is being ignored, but I can't test it.

**EDIT** Adding a ssh session without the nc line on the config file:

```
ssh 55.66.77.88 -v
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 16: Applying options for 55.66.77.88
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 55.66.77.88 [55.66.77.88] port 22.
```

and with the `nc` on the `config` file:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 16: Applying options for 55.66.77.88
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec nc -X connect -x proxy.corporation.br:8080 55.66.77.88 22
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1000
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Host '[55.66.77.88]:22' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@55.66.77.88's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 55.66.77.88 (via proxy).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = pt_BR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = pt_BR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = pt_BR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = pt_BR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = pt_BR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = pt_BR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = pt_BR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = pt_BR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = pt_BR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = pt_BR.UTF-
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the use of the `NO_PROXY` environment variable.  It means that you should **not** use the HTTP proxy server when connecting to the hosts/domains/IPs listed in the variable.  In the case of your remote host at `55.66.77.88`, I believe you **do** want the proxy, at least when inside the restrictive network.

When you ran your experiment and it failed to connect with the IP in `NO_PROXY`, did you still have the `ProxyCommand` line in your `.ssh/config` file?  If so, remove the IP and try again.

Alternatively, if you are trying to avoid changing your ssh config file for each host which needs the proxy, you can add a directive to a `Host *` entry that will proxy via a custom script.  That script could connect via the proxy only to hosts that it cannot reach directly.  I have a script on my github (called ssh-proxy) which does that, and more.

Comment: No, really, the network configuration here says that to connect to the 55.66.77.88 machine I don't want to pass through the proxy. I also tried removing the nc line on my config file, no luck.

Comment: Can you paste the (sanitized) output of your ssh session?  Include '-v' option to see more details.